# Datatable integration fails with error "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'dataTable' "

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datatable

I want to use DataTables for various functionalities for our tables. I am unable to fix the issue.

My code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=Constants.JSROOTURL%>jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//datatables.net/download/build/jquery.dataTables.nightly.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var jq = jQuery.noConflict();
    jq(document).ready( function(){
        jq("#results").dataTable();
    });
</script>
```

Error says:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'dataTable' imageValidation.html:234
(anonymous function) imageValidation.html:234
n jquery.min.js:2
o.fireWith jquery.min.js:2
e.extend.ready jquery.min.js:2
c.addEventListener.B
```

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Have all your scripts definitely loaded? Check your developer tools to see if they have...

Comment: Why are you including both jQuery and datatables twice? Please make sure everything loads...

Comment: You are loading a local version of datatables before you load jQuery, which will cause an error, and you are then loading a CDN version of datatables, which will possibly cause an error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cut out the 1st 2 of your `script` tags (the comments are as an example, they should actually be **deleted**):

```
<!--
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=Constants.JSROOTURL%>jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script> 
-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//datatables.net/download/build/jquery.dataTables.nightly.js"></script>
```

You should not loading and reloading the libraries, that could screw things up...

Also it is not usually a good idea to use a nightly build of a plugin... could be buggy in production, just use `http://datatables.net/download/build/jquery.dataTables.js`

Comment: If I put "http://" instead of "//", I get an error saying, "[blocked] The page at https://localhost:1043/imageValidation.html ran insecure content from http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js."

How to resolve this? I am not using https explicitly.

Comment: @instanceOfObject dont use https

Comment: sorry for obvious question but where am I using https explicitly? My URL is https bcoz it will run on HTTPS even at production.

Comment: @instanceOfObject well then use https instead of http

Comment: I manged to fix that issue but now I get "TypeError: Cannot read property 'asSorting' of undefined". Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The second time you load jQuery, all plugins are gone. Remove your third  tag that loads jQuery again.

Comment: Thanks Lian but I still face the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use CDN version of Jquery. Download Jquery and data table plugin. Here is example

```
<!doctype html>
 <html>
  <head>
   <title>jQuery datagrid</title>

   <style type="text/css" title="currentStyle">
        @import "css/jquery.dataTables.css";
    </style>

   <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
   <script  src="js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
   <script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
         $('#example').dataTable();
       } );
  </script>

</head>
  <body>
    <div id="dvContent">
     <table id="example">
        <thead>
            <tr><th>One</th><th>Two</th></tr>
       </thead>
        <tbody>

        </tbody>
     </table>
    </div>

 </body>
```